# requests.get not working anymore in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to access the page source of various Netflix titles in my own "My list" page, for example page source of "https://www.netflix.com/se-en/title/70195800"
The code I'm using:

```
import requests
import re

with open ("netflix_mylist.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.readlines()
    data=data[0]   # Contains a section of "Inspect->Elements" page source called "<div class="galleryContent"> ==$0"


movieName = re.findall(r'"fallback-text">(.*?)<', data)         # List of 50 elements containing the names of the Netflix titles
movieNumber = re.findall(r'watch/(.*?)\?', data)                # List of 50 elements containing the unique URL numbers (not complete links)
movieCover = re.findall(r'padded-container" src="(.*?)"', data) # List of 50 elements containing the complete URLS of the Netflix title covers


movieNumberURL=[]
for i in range(len(movieNumber)):
    movieNumberURL.append("https://www.netflix.com/se-en/title/"+movieNumber[i])    # List of 50 complete URLs of the Netflix titles


movieNamelist=[]
tvNamelist=[]

for i in range(len(movieName)):
    read_link = requests.get(movieNumberURL[i])  # Request to get the page source of each unique Netflix title in "MY list"-page.
    linkHTML=read_link.text   # 1 single string of each page source

    if 'seasonCount":' in linkHTML:  # The 'seasonCount":' word only exists in web pages of TV-shows. This is one way to separate pages of movies and TV-shows.
        tvNamelist.append(movieName[i])

    else:
        movieNamelist.append(movieName[i])

print(len(movieNamelist))
print(movieNamelist)
print("\n")

print(len(tvNamelist))
print(tvNamelist)
```

The crazy thing is that it actually worked perfectly well the first two-three times. The printed lists contained the correct elements, meaning movie names were in the movieNamelist and TV-shows were in the tvNamelist.

Why did it suddenly stop working? And how do I solve this problem?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not working? Have you check if get() is receiving the correct URL to fetch?

Comment: @mquasar so instead of printing 41 movie elements in movieNamelist and 9 TV-shows in  tvNamelist, as in the intital successful attempt, it now prints just prints the first list containing all 50 titles (both movies and TV-shows) and the second list is empty.

Comment: The "linkHTML" strings in "linkHTML=read_link.text" are coming out as empty strings.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be a problem with the get() method. It could be that the returned HTML changed so the seasonCount criteria is not met anymore. I suggest you take a look at the contents of the read_link variable.

Comment: I would suggest a small change in your code, not related to the problem you are having.
Instead of using range(len(somelist)), use the enumerate method:
for i, elem in enumrate(somelist):

Comment: @mquasar I used a VPN and changed location from Sweden to the US. The code, though slow, actually worked again. So I think I realized that the problem is with Netflix not allowing request.get to work multiple times on their URLs. Cause before activating VPN, when it didn't work, the web page in incognito mode of an arbitrary title from "My list" said: "Access to www.netflix.com was denied. You don't have authorization to view this page. HTTP ERROR 403." So it has do with netflix. Is there another way to get the URLs all the time without the need to use VPN?

Comment: I would suggest you wait a few seconds between each requests. The access denied message could be caused by the number of hits in a short amount of time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239647/discussion-between-gojira-and-mquasar).